# Stubbing ActiveRecord result aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-activerecord, factory-bot, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to stub an alias introduced to each ActiveRecord result by the Geocoder gem. I am using Factory Girl to mock records.

In my controller I am using the `near` method to find some nearby venues. I am mocking the `near` method and returning results created by Factory girl:

```
let(:origin) { [...] }
let(:venue)  { build(:venue) 

...

expect(Venue).to receive(:near).with(origin).and_return([venue] * 5)
```

This is all fine but in my view I am expecting to be able to fetch the distance calculated from the origin to the venue:

```
- @nearest_venues.each do |venue|
  = "#{venue.name}, #{'%.2f' % venue.distance} miles"
```

However this will explode because `distance` is not a implemented by the venue model. At first I thought I could add a distance property to the result using Factory Girl traits but this will fail for the same reason.

I'm fairly new to RoR so I am aware I may be trying to force square pegs into round holes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be thinking about testing different components of your app together (which is more for integration/acceptance-level tests, such as provided by Capybara). If you check out the [rspec-rails](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/) docs I think you'll find some good examples, for example the model spec here (similar to your Venue test):

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/#Model_Specs

Or view tests here:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/#View_specs

These test different things--the view specs are more concerned with rendering and variable assignment and such, while model specs focus on things like calculations, similar to your test.

Mocks and stubs are covered here:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/

And of course you can just create a plain old Ruby class with your target method (like `distance`) and use that as a test double, too.

Comment: You're quite right, I'm crossing testing concerns in this case. Thanks for your response.